# replace strings in array without loop

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have an array like this:

```
$myArray = array("Value 1", "Value 2");
```

Now I would like to do a "str_replace", but for an array? How ?

My idea:
A foreach loop to get all values, do the str_replace and save the new value to the same array position.

But is there another solution ?

Comment: Input/Output example would be nice for clarity. I presume you will also need to consider overlapping replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply the array as an argument to `str_replace()` and it will return an array of the replaced strings:

```
$newArray = str_replace('Value', 'NewValue', $myArray);
```